# How do I clean up after feeding a toddler food that my spouse is allergic to?

Tags: food, allergies

My wife is allergic to X. It was recommended to me by an allergist to feed X to my toddler 3 times a week,

The problem is my toddler likes to kiss us on the cheek, and we share similar food (e.g. an apple). If my toddler had traces X in his mouth, it might cause my wife to react when he kisses her (it has happened before when I had traces of X and I kissed her).

My toddler isn't old enough to know how to brush his teeth or rinse his mouth. What are some ways to ensure my toddler doesn't cause my wife to react after consuming X?

Comment: Could you ask the allergist who recommended this food for your toddler?

Answer (score 4):

This should be a good introduction into learning how to do those things that you mention in your last paragraph. Explain to him that even though "X" is yummy to eat, it makes mommy very sick so whenever we eat it and, really, whenever we eat anything, we should practice proper hygiene and wipe our hands and mouth after we eat it.

Teach him how to and help him wash around his mouth. Keep a wet cloth on hand making sure you always follow-up his cleaning until you feel he's thorough enough to not leave traces behind. Teach him how to properly wash his hands. Also, have a plastic cup by the sink to fill with water so he can rinse his mouth out too.

If it gets too bad, talk to your allergist to determine if this procedure of feeding him 3 times a week can be discontinued until he is older and more capable of taking care of his hygiene.

Answer (score 1):

It is an ongoing struggle to get my 6 yo to wash up after eating things my 4 yo is allergic to.  Be vigilant and help with washing hands and face after eating.

You mention that you have kissed your partner and caused allergy issues. Until he learns to wash out his mouth, she might have fewer issues if your child kisses her only on the cheek instead of the mouth, at least after eating allergens.  This might be less restrictive in a parent-child context than it would on romantic partners.